# HP QTP. Is there a function that gets called affix flags to filter - Node type - Reporter and Action

Tags: qtp

HP QTP. Is there a function that gets called affix flags to filter - Node type -  Reporter and Action. For example there is a function: Reporter.Filter = [Status] , I also need something like this: Reporter.Filter = [Node Type]. 
Do you know of whom such function? Yes I can put down manually through the filter, but I need to function through

Answer (score 0):

QTP does not provide any built-in function to filter by nodetype. But it stores the results in an XML file. You can write a function which parses that XML file and retrieve only the nodes that you need.